# Yii2 Basic call action from different controller

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Is it possible to call action from a controller in different view ?

example

I have 2 controllers : **Post** and **Blog** , so I want to call `actionCreate` from post but inside blog view not in post view. I have 2 **views** and 2 **controllers** :

```
view :
 1. views/blog/view
 2. views/post/view

controller
 1. controllers/blogController.php
 2. controllers/postController.php
```

controllers/PostController.php :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model_Post = new Post();

    if ($model_Post->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model_Post->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model_Post->Post_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('/blog/view', [
            'model_Post' => $model_Post,
        ]);
    }
}
```

views/blog/view.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Likectt */

$this->title = $model->Blog_id;

?>
<div class="blog-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->Blog_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->Blog_id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'Blog_id',
            'Blog_title',
            'Blog_text',
            'User_id',
            'Category_id',
        ],
    ]) ?>

    <?= Yii::$app->runAction('PostController/actionCreate', ['model_Post'=>$model_Post]);?>

</div>
```

Comment: if given answer helps you please accept the answer

Comment: you never selected the answer from your previous questions although they have answers submitted, that's kinda bit odd when someone takes out time for you and you don't mark the answer as correct as it would help others solving the problem too, please take out some time to mark the correct answer or give feedback if they are not correct

Comment: still not fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that :

In you blog view :

```
Yii::$app->runAction('postController/actionCreate', ['param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2']);
```

Comment: I get this error : Undefined variable: model_post. On PostController inside actionCreate I have : return $this->render('/blog/view', [
                'model_post' => $model_post,
            ]);. And in views/blog/view I add : <?= Yii::$app->runAction('PostController/actionCreate', ['model_post'=>$model_post]);?> . But I get the error message